# Passing objects that implement an interface with a pointer receiver

Tags: go

I understand that this has to do with the fact that Scale takes a pointer receiver. But I don't understand how I need to write PrintArea so this works.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Shape interface {
        Scale(num float64)
        Area() float64
}

type Square struct {
        edge float64
}

func (s *Square) Scale(num float64) {
        s.edge *= num
}

func (s Square) Area() float64 {
        return s.edge * s.edge
}

func PrintArea(s Shape) {
        fmt.Println(s.Area())
}

func main() {
        s := Square{10}
        PrintArea(s)
}
```

Here is the error I get as is.

```
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/sandbox126043885/main.go:30: cannot use s (type Square) as type Shape in argument to PrintArea:
    Square does not implement Shape (Scale method has pointer receiver)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Shape` interface requires that the receiver has two methods - `Scale` and `Area`.  Pointers to a type and the types themselves are considered different types in Go (so `*Square` and `Square` are different types).

To implement the interface, the `Area` and `Scale` functions must be on either the type or the pointer (or both if you want).  So either

```
func (s *Square) Scale(num float64) {
    s.edge *= num
}

func (s *Square) Area() float64 {
    return s.edge * s.edge
}

func main() {
    s := Square{10}
    PrintArea(&s)
}
```

Comment: The 2nd example will not work, the original `s.edge` will stay the same after calling Scale.

Comment: @OneOfOne - right - the compile error goes away, but the application logic isn't correct.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass by reference

```
PrintArea(&s)
```